# Catch failing connection to directline WebSocket endpoint

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I am trying to figure out a way to catch failing connections to the WebSocket stream endpoint of directline (for example `wss://europe.directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/...`) to be able to fall back to the polling mechanism.
**Use case example:** In some corporate networks WebSocket stream connections are blocked by a proxy etc or some plugins block WebSocket streams. If that is the case (resulting in the console error by direcline.js that the connection could not be established) I want to fall back to the polling so the affected users are still able to use the bot.

I already have the functioning fallback if the directline `connectionStatus` is `4` / `FailedToConnect` resulting in the `DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_REJECTED` action in the store. But if the connection via wss fails the directline connectionStatus is still `2` / `Online` resulting in the `DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED` store action, which makes sense since it got a conversationId and token. So I am searching for a way to detect and then handle the failed wss connection.
Also the directline object (that also holds the connectionStatus) does not change when the error is thrown and `connectionStatus.hasError` stays `false` and the `connectionStatus.thrownError` stays `null`.

Do you have experiences, insights, or ideas on how I could be able to achieve the detection of the failed wss connection?